# Remove some content from regular expression Php

Tags: php, regex, string

I have wrote an regular expression that removed all the content from once bracket to end of bracket, But its not working, I wrote a explode code but its not working properly, anyone have an regular expression from that i can remove brackets and content inside them

Here is my code for explode:

```
$arr = explode(". ", $des);
$arr2= explode("(", $arr[0]);
$arr3=explode(")", $arr2[1]);
$arr[0]=$arr2[0].$arr3[1];
```

Please anyone provide me regular express from that

e.g: I am a web developer ($123.Abc) and I am from US.

I need to remove ($123.Abc) from the above line..

Please help!!!

Comment: i dont want to add this as an answer because regex info is available all over the internet, but `preg_replace('/\(.+\) /', '', $des)`

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this should do the job, if I understand well what you intend to do:

```
$target = preg_replace('~\([^)]*\)~', '', $des);
```

It finds all occurrences of ( followed by any number of any character which is not ) followed by ) and replaces them by an empty string.

Comment: What about the closing bracket? "I need to remove ($123.Abc)"....

Comment: You have no delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use regex you can use the regex in the [castis comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30268373/remove-some-content-from-regular-expression-php#comment48636671_30268373):

```
<?php

$string = 'I am a web developer ($123.Abc) and I am from US.';
$new_string = preg_replace('/\(.+\) /', '', $string);

echo $new_string . PHP_EOL;
?>
```

An if you want to use explode, should be something like this:

```
$string = 'I am a web developer ($123.Abc) and I am from US.';
$array = explode('(', $string);
$array1 = explode(')', $string); 
$new_string = $array[0] . $array1[1];

echo $new_string . PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: @DeDevelopers you got some advance?